# Laravel Dropbox API v2 - Empty File on Upload

Tags: php, laravel, dropbox-api

**What I have till now**

Right now I have a working oauth2 authentication between a laravel user and the dropbox API. Every user can upload files to their personal folder.

**The Problem**

After Uploading a file with laravel with the Dropbox API v2 I can see that there is a empty (0 Bytes) file uploaded.

Used to accomplish this task:

- Laravel
- Guzzle
- Dropbox API Library

What am I missing?

**The Code**

My function for processing a form looks like this:

```
$formFile = $request->file('fileToUpload');
$path = $formFile->getClientOriginalName();
$file = $formFile->getPathName();
$result = Dropbox::files()->upload($path, $file);
return redirect('dropboxfiles');
```

And my files->upload function in my Dropbox Library looks like this:

```
$client = new Client;

   $response = $client->post("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload", [
      'headers' => [
         'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$this->getAccessToken(),
         'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
         'Dropbox-API-Arg' => json_encode([
            'path' => $path,
            'mode' => 'add',
            'autorename' => true,
            'mute' => true,
            'strict_conflict' => false
          ])
       ],
       'data-binary' => '@'.$file
   ]);
```

The file, as I said, gets uploaded successfully. Correct name, but 0 Bytes. So empty file.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

**Update**

With the following code I made it work. My question is though if there is a better "Laravel-Like" Solution instead of using `fopen`?

```
$response = $client->post("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload", [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$this->getAccessToken(),
                'Dropbox-API-Arg' => json_encode([
                    'path' => $path,
                    'mode' => 'add',
                    'autorename' => true,
                    'mute' => true,
                    'strict_conflict' => false
                ]),
                'Content-Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
            ],
            'body' => fopen($file, "r"),
        ]);
```

Comment: I think you are looking for https://github.com/spatie/flysystem-dropbox which uses League/filesystem under the hood

Comment: @alithedeveloper I'm not quite sure. Right now I'm using daveismyname's Dropbox Package. With this package I allow a User to connect to their own Dropbox account and save app files there. With spaties flysystem i think i will just have the possibility to have an additional storage filesystem if i'm not wrong.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Dropbox-API-v2-Empty-file-on-upload/m-p/392295#M21655 ]

Comment: Thank you so much @Greg for the explanation! Feel free to add your solution from the cross-link here so I can mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

How @Greg mentioned ([see](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Dropbox-API-v2-Empty-file-on-upload/m-p/392295#M21655) cross-linking reference) I was able to solve this issue by using

```
'body' => fopen($file, "r"),
```

instead of

```
'data-binary' => '@'.$file
```

This is, how Greg mentioned, because `data-binary` is used in Curl requests. Other HTTP Clients, like Guzzle in my case use different names.