# Node-Red Dropbox node

Tags: dropbox-api, node-red

I am using the node-red-node-dropbox and have my flow working to do the following:

1. Check if the file exists using File Access, and if it does, upload it.
2. once the file is uploaded, get notified that there was a change, and get the name and path, and delete the local file, if it exists.
   Below is my test low I am using to debug.
   [image]

Results:
The file gets uploaded to the directory if it exists. Then gets deleted. all works as planned.
the issue is when I go to the file on drop box, the file is only a few bytes in size, vs. the expected KB or sometimes MB.
I did some research on a similar issue, and found the following:
[Laravel Dropbox API v2 - Empty File on Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59904691/laravel-dropbox-api-v2-empty-file-on-upload)

Now I will say, I am not a programmer. I am working on a home project, and trying to move a timelapse GIF from my local Rpi to the dropbox folders.

any help is really appreciate it. If there is an update, a hack, a workaround, I will take anything.

Here is my test flow:

```
[{"id":"4fd3d436.eb8fcc","type":"tab","label":"DropBox","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"8e054ce8.884b","type":"function","z":"4fd3d436.eb8fcc","name":"name gif","func":"msg.path = \"/home/pi/.node-red/static/gif/old/\";\n\nmsg.filename = \"img20201027_144920.gif\";\n\nmsg.payload = msg.path + msg.filename\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","x":420,"y":180,"wires":[["15144f44.cf7dc1"]]},{"id":"2377960c.da806a","type":"dropbox out","z":"4fd3d436.eb8fcc","dropbox":"","filename":"","localFilename":"","name":"Dropbox","x":1020,"y":180,"wires":[]},{"id":"7a40742d.26a4dc","type":"inject","z":"4fd3d436.eb8fcc","name":"","props":[{"p":"payload"},{"p":"topic","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","x":240,"y":180,"wires":[["8e054ce8.884b"]]},{"id":"41e83491.8e6dbc","type":"dropbox in","z":"4fd3d436.eb8fcc","dropbox":"","filepattern":"","name":"","x":220,"y":280,"wires":[["5941e355.c66b9c"]]},{"id":"3003a90.8933658","type":"function","z":"4fd3d436.eb8fcc","name":"gif name","func":"msg.path = \"/home/pi/.node-red/static/gif/old/\";\n\nmsg.filename = msg.file;\n\nmsg.payload = msg.path + msg.filename\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","x":560,"y":280,"wires":[["3eeef854.713178"]]},{"id":"5941e355.c66b9c","type":"delay","z":"4fd3d436.eb8fcc","name":"","pauseType":"delay","timeout":"5","timeoutUnits":"seconds","rate":"1","nbRateUnits":"1","rateUnits":"second","randomFirst":"1","randomLast":"5","randomUnits":"seconds","drop":false,"x":400,"y":280,"wires":[["3003a90.8933658"]]},{"id":"9d041a38.f66f48","type":"exec","z":"4fd3d436.eb8fcc","command":"rm ","addpay":true,"append":"","useSpawn":"false","timer":"","oldrc":false,"name":"","x":1110,"y":280,"wires":[[],[],[]]},{"id":"77b26b64.855c54","type":"comment","z":"4fd3d436.eb8fcc","name":"Delete local file","info":"Once the file is on dropbox, get the path and file name and delete the local file then","x":240,"y":240,"wires":[]},{"id":"15144f44.cf7dc1","type":"fs-ops-access","z":"4fd3d436.eb8fcc","name":"","path":"path","pathType":"msg","filename":"filename","filenameType":"msg","read":true,"write":true,"throwerror":false,"x":590,"y":180,"wires":[["f0f07147.1b318"],[]]},{"id":"f0f07147.1b318","type":"change","z":"4fd3d436.eb8fcc","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"filename","pt":"msg","to":"payload","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":810,"y":180,"wires":[["2377960c.da806a"]]},{"id":"22c79cc5.761a64","type":"comment","z":"4fd3d436.eb8fcc","name":"Upload local file","info":"Check if the file exists locally. If it does, then upload it to dropbox","x":240,"y":140,"wires":[]},{"id":"3eeef854.713178","type":"fs-ops-access","z":"4fd3d436.eb8fcc","name":"","path":"path","pathType":"msg","filename":"filename","filenameType":"msg","read":true,"write":true,"throwerror":false,"x":730,"y":280,"wires":[["2ef8b77b.eb0658"],[]]},{"id":"2ef8b77b.eb0658","type":"change","z":"4fd3d436.eb8fcc","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"filename","pt":"msg","to":"payload","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":930,"y":280,"wires":[["9d041a38.f66f48"]]}]
```

Comment: Usually when this happens, it's because a string (like the file name) is being uploaded to Dropbox, rather than the file itself. Make sure you're passing the file to Dropbox and not just the file name!

Comment: @TaylorKrusen, thanks for the response. I am passing the file location to the dropbox node. It only gets passed when it is available using the file access node. I am passing the whole path. Do you know the format for the path and filename I need to be sending? It is not clear from the documentation of the node. I thought i was doing it right, but clearly I am not given the results.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the flow and added the readdir to create a list of all the files in the directory.

[image: Updated Flow]

The settings for the readdir are:

[image: Readdir settings]

I basically point to the directory where all my files are, and upload them one at a time by setting them to the msg.filename property of the payload. That's what the Dropbox node needs. Works great now.